# Cron task not running

Tags: shell-script, cron, node.js, javascript

I've configure a cron task for running a NodeJS script everyday.

`crontab -l`

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
55 23 * * * /usr/bin/node /getGames/.
```

But my script is never executed (the script write data on a file, and the last modification time of this file is never updated.) When I run the script manually, it's working.

I've no idea why it's not working

Comment: are you sure that this actually runs? ... `/usr/bin/node /getGames/.`

Comment: Is your parameter for the node command `/getGames/.` (including the dot)? Is /getGames/ in your root directory?

Comment: Yeah, /usr/bin/node /getGames/. exist (/usr/bin/node /getGames/index.js)

Comment: The command /usr/bin/node /getGames/. run manually

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: Even with a bash script, cron not running

Comment: Did you compare your desktop environment with the `cron` environment?

Comment: How to show env of cron ?

Comment: I showed the commands to use in my answer, what don't you understand?

Comment: When i run `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` it shows the env of 'root', how to show env of cron